# WP - Best way to store theme colors to use in SASS/SCSS, JSX (blocks) and PHP

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, javascript, block-editor

I want to have a way to change theme colors once and use them in SCSS, JSX and PHP.

Right now I have the theme colors in my `variables.scss` like:

```
$theme-colors: (
  base: #fff,
  primary: #5bb57a,
  secondary: #f39708,
  tertiary: #ed7aad,
);
```

Now, I want to mainly use it in combination with JSX to create custom blocks and access the colors as an object in the block editor. (to use it with an color pallet and to store the object key to an attribute)

How can I change the colors once and access them cross language?

Comment: Perhaps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178555/591486 - store variables in JSON, which is accessible to most other languages.

Comment: If your question isn't getting attention, edit it to improve it and make it easier to understand so it becomes more prominent. Posting the same question again is just spamming the site and will trigger anti-spam mechanisms ( and annoy people on the site ). I've closed this question as a duplicate of the question you asked 3 hours ago. ( note that the anti-spam system can also see deleted questions )